# Использование LENGTH против CHAR_LENGTH

Tags: sql, mysql

В книге пишут, что  `CHAR_LENGTH` возвращает число символов в строке,  в отличии от `LENGTH` подсчет ведется посимвольно, поэтому функция работает с многобайтовыми кодировками.

Нашел вот такие примеры:

```
  select length(_utf8 '€'), char_length(_utf8 '€')// 3 1
```

Также пишут, что в русских буквах та самая ситуация. Но опыт повторить мне не удалось

```
select length('ЇТЮУ'), char_length('ЇТЮУ');//4 4
```

Так в каких случаях нужно применять функцию `LENGTH` для подсчета символов в строке? Я так понимаю, что лучше всегда использовать `char_length`?

Comment: смотря что вам надо считать. length - в байтах, char_length в символах. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Так зачем эти байты практически нужны?

Comment: например, чтобы выдать правильный Content-length

Comment: А можно пример или статью определение Content-length  ?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP#.D0.94.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы повторить опыт, переведите в UTF8:

```
 select length(_utf8 'ф'), char_length(_utf8 'ф');
```

2; 1
Или для вашего примера:

```
 select length(_utf8 'ЇТЮУ'), char_length(_utf8 'ЇТЮУ');
```

8; 4